# dynamic calling of php array values to insert into new array on same level

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

UPDATE: Solved answer at bottom.

My current Code:

```
//$PerLineData is an array that contains 2 assoc arrays
$postData = ['WeightAndDimension' =>
        [
            [
                "SKU" => $sku, "CartonQty" => (float)checkCaseQty($perLineData)],
                $perLineData
        ]
    ];

return json_encode($postData);
```

The Output (I have marked the values with accuratevalue as this part is all fine, the data doesn't matter)

```
{
    "WeightAndDimension": [{
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue
        },
        [//remove this
        {
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue,
            "TUN": "accuratevalue",
            "Volume": accuratevalue,
            "VolumetricWeight": accuratevalue,
            "Weight": accuratevalue,
            "Length": accuratevalue,
            "Width": accuratevalue,
            "Depth": accuratevalue
        }, {
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue,
            "TUN": "accuratevalue",
            "Volume": accuratevalue,
            "VolumetricWeight": accuratevalue,
            "Weight": accuratevalue,
            "Length": accuratevalue,
            "Width": accuratevalue,
            "Depth": accuratevalue
        }
        ]//remove this
    ]
}
```

My question is how to remove the [] brackets that i have commented next to, the $perLineData array can contain 1-3 lines, I can hard code around this but want to be able to dynamically call the array values.

eg

replacing `$perLineData` with `$perLineData[0], $perLineData[1]` solves the issue, returing the following:

```
{
    "WeightAndDimension": [{
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue
        },{
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue,
            "TUN": "accuratevalue",
            "Volume": accuratevalue,
            "VolumetricWeight": accuratevalue,
            "Weight": accuratevalue,
            "Length": accuratevalue,
            "Width": accuratevalue,
            "Depth": accuratevalue
        }, {
            "SKU": "accuratevalue",
            "CartonQty": accuratevalue,
            "TUN": "accuratevalue",
            "Volume": accuratevalue,
            "VolumetricWeight": accuratevalue,
            "Weight": accuratevalue,
            "Length": accuratevalue,
            "Width": accuratevalue,
            "Depth": accuratevalue
        }
    ]
}
```

RE: @CBroe 's suggestion, I tried the following:
(Update: I Did it properly and it worked)

```
$sqlPerSku = "SELECT * FROM cubiscan WHERE reviewed = 1 AND `ProductID` = '" . $sku . "';";
    $resultPerSku = mysqli_query($db, $sqlPerSku) or die ($sqlPerSku . mysqli_error($db));

    $perLineData = [];


    while ($rowPerSku = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultPerSku)) {


        $perLineData[] = [
                "SKU" =>  $rowPerSku['ProductID'],
                "CartonQty" => (float)$rowPerSku['Qty'],
                "TUN" => tunCreator($rowPerSku['Qty'],$rowPerSku['ProductID']),
                "Volume" => (((float)$rowPerSku['Length']*(float)$rowPerSku['Width']*(float)$rowPerSku['Height'])/1000), /*need to modify this*/
                "VolumetricWeight" => (((float)$rowPerSku['Length']*(float)$rowPerSku['Width']*(float)$rowPerSku['Height'])/1000), /*need to modify this*/
                "Weight" => (float)$rowPerSku['Weight'],
                "Length" => (float)$rowPerSku['Length']*10,
                "Width" => (float)$rowPerSku['Width']*10,
                "Depth" => (float)$rowPerSku['Height']*10
                ];
    }

    $postData = [];

    array_unshift($perLineData, ["SKU" => $sku, "CartonQty" => (float)checkCaseQty($perLineData)]);

    $postData = ['WeightAndDimension' => $perLineData];

return json_encode($postData);
```

This worked perfectly, Thanks

Comment: Instead of adding a new item “next” to `$perLineData`, add a new item _into_ `$perLineData`, via `array_unshift`. And then set the result of that operation as the value under the `WeightAndDimension` key.

Comment: @CBroe I Tried that, not sure if i did what you were suggesting correctly though.

Will update main post.

Comment: Looks a bit the wrong way around. Why are you creating this array with nine elements from your database query, I thought these elements were what you _had_ as input data in $perLineData, and only one new item with SKU and CartonQty was supposed to be added at the start?

Comment: Understand now, thanks for that, works like a charm, idk if i can mark a comment as an answer or not. Will update main post.